# Detect loops in computer player in a cardgame

Tags: javascript, algorithm

A while ago I created a small cardgame web app for fun. The player plays against the computer and mostly it works fine. Sometimes though the computer player gets into a loop, the point of the game is to lose all your cards and if you don't have a card to play you take the pile. Sometimes the computer plays x,y,z, takes the pile, plays x,yz, takes the pile etc.

I keep track of the moves I've made, so at any point I have an array that looks something like : [C2,D5,**H2,S4,C5,H2,S4,C5,H2,S4,C5**]

In this case I can see that I've gotten into a loop of playing H2,S4,C5, then taking the pile and then repeating.

So, the generalized problem is, what's the best way to detect repeating patterns in a list? I could probably whip something up using a simple for loop, trying to find the card I'm about to play and if I find that in position x then I could check whether the pattern from x to n repeats at position x-(n-x) to x, but this seems like the kind of problem that could have a nice algorithm for it. How would you code this given the following function signature:

```
function findLoops(previousMoves, nextMove, maxPatternLength) {
    //Return [loopLength, loopCount] or null if there are no loops
}
```

p.s. this is not a homework assignment, the game exists and is at http://www.idiot-cardgame.com if anyone is interested :)

Comment: @delnan: Floyds algorithm would not help much

Comment: That's a very addicting and fun game. Thanks for the link. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the general question: Your suggested method

> trying to find the card I'm about to play and if I find that in position x then I could check whether the pattern from x to n repeats at position x-(n-x) to x,

looks really good.  I would suggest basically the same.  It is O(n) and needs a fixed amount of storage, and  is simple: what else would you wish for?

Second: You can check for repetition in games generally if you keep a hash table of all previous game states (complete state, nothing left out).  Everytime you reach a new state look up if it is in the hashtable, if its in it: you game state is looping.

In Javascript you have builtin hastables so this is very easy to do with something similar like this:

```
 new_state = next_move(old_state);
 new_encoded_state = encode(new_state);  // make it into a string
 if (allstates[new_encoded_state]) {
       // we are looping!
 } else {
       allstates[new_encoded_state] = 1;
       // no looping
 }
```

The variable `allstates` is not an Array but of type Object.  You can have array like access with strings and this uses the Object as hastable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll probably end up implementing my own solution, perhaps adding in some params for how many times the loop should occur etc. As for the second suggestion, it is possible for the same state to come up more than once without it being a problem, however maybe it would be a good idea to use a hash + a counter, e.g. if we're in this state for the third time then it's time to do something different. Actually I'll probably do that, it sounds simpler and encoding the entire state is easy.

Comment: The funny thing is that the loop isn't really a loop, because at any point the human player can choose to take the pile instead of playing a card, i.e. he can do a suboptimal move to move the game along if he sees that it is looping. However, some users absolutely won't take the pile if they have a card that they play and then they complain that game is broken, so instead I'll let the computer run the loop maybe 2 or 3 times, and then yield by taking the pile if the human absolutely won't :)

Comment: Breaking out of the loop after 3 iterations sounds good.  BTW it is always nice to have a give me the whole state as a string function (like my encode) function, because you can use the same function for debugging and logging if you make the string readable.